# Series involving log

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\lambda >0$ and $a>0$. I want to evaluate :
$$\sum_{\ell=2}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{ \ell^4-\lambda\ell^2-1+\lambda}{a+\ell^4-\lambda\ell^2+1-\lambda}\right)\\
$$

I am particularly interested  by tracking $\lambda$ and $a$.

Comment: Ouch. What is the origin of such series and what have you attempted? Are you aware of the Weierstrass products for the sine and cosine functions?

Comment: This looks hard.

Comment: The serie come from a representation theorem. The coefficient are certain eigenvalues

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. By the Weierstrass product for the sine and cosine functions
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+A^2}\right)=\frac{A\sinh\left(\pi\sqrt{1+A^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+A^2}\sinh(\pi A)} \tag{1}$$
hence you just have to factor a biquadratic polynomial as $(n^2+A^2)(n^2+B^2)$, apply $(1)$, reindex and take the logarithm.

Comment: I have atempted first to compare it with an integral. Now I'am more interested to write as a Weiertrass product as you suggested. I have not been able to factor the polynomial involved.

Comment: @Amadeus: if you are able to find the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ you should also be able to write $ax^4+bx^2+c$ as $a(x^2+J)(x^2+K)$.

Comment: $$-\log\prod_{\ell=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{a+ 2(1-\lambda)}{(\ell^2-1)(\ell^2+1-\lambda)}\right)
$$

Comment: I come to this expression with the factors. Still don't know How to Use the Weierstrass Product